# lwjgl, slick-util and NetBeans 7.4 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, lwjgl

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBK-lb-k-rs&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5 , which is on create a game engine using lwjgl, slick-util and java.

I am trying to run this code, however, although no errors are shown (compiles successfully), no windows open.

Screenshot of NB 7.4:

[image]

Project Setup:

[image]

Code:

- Main.java - http://pastebin.com/hZswypxv
- Window.java - http://pastebin.com/azrWWHwN
- Time.java - http://pastebin.com/KBeDUM3d
- Game.java - http://pastebin.com/Veq40mZJ (only contains empty methods - as per #3 video)

What is happening?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me. I'm not sure, maybe you don't link the natives? (Although then you should get an error message). Maybe you can check your IDE setup with http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_NetBeans

Comment: @SebastianHöffner I followed those instructions exactly, however, still the same problem.